# How to get all facebook photos after login with Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using this to get all photos and other information but i am not getting all photos after login user.Below is the code that i am using to get information.

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name,email,cover,albums{picture},picture.type(large),likes,relationship_status,gender,birthday,locale,work,friends,education,age_range,interested_in");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAndWait();
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

Comment: @CBroe can u plz describe me what exactly code I have to write i am using above fields to get the all photos.